# Can ensemble classifiers underperform the best single classifier?

Tags: r, ensemble-learning, mlr

I have recently run an ensemble classifier in MLR (R) of a multicenter data set. I noticed that the ensemble over three classifiers (that were trained on different data modalities) was worse than the best classifier. 
This seemed to be unexpected to me. I was using logistic regressions (without any parameter optimization) as simple classifier and a Partial Least Squares (PLS) Discriminant Analysis as a superlearner, since the base-learner predictions ought to be correlated. I also tested different superlearners like NB, and logistic regression. The results did not change.

Here are my specific questions:

1) Do you know, whether this can in principle occur?
(I also googled a bit and found this blog that seems to indicate that it can:
https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2017/03/10/are-ensemble-classifiers-always-better-than-single-classifiers/)

2) Especially, if you are as surprised as I was, do you know of any checks I could do in mlr to make sure, that there isnt a bug. I have tried to use a different cross-validation scheme (originally I used leave-center-out CV, but since some centers provided very little data, I wasnt sure, whether this might lead to weird model fits of the super learner), but it still holds. I also tried to combine different data modalities and they give me the same phenomenon.

I would be grateful to hear, whether you have experienced this and if not, whether you know what the problem could be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What data is the ensemble worse on? A hold-out test set? A training set? Something else?

Comment: Yes, this can absolutely happen and is not a bug, especially if you train the different models on different parts of the data.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! @Gregor: The performance is worse on the test set. I noticed that it might be related to severe imbalance in the cross validation folds (due to differential amount of data from each center). When I do not take the average of the average performance of each CV fold, but compute the performance directly on all the single predictions the ensemble shows indeed superior performance for most of the cases that I looked at yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can happen - ensembles do not always guarantee a better result. More details regarding cases where this can happen are discussed also in [this cross-validate question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255230/how-do-ensemble-methods-outperform-all-their-constituents)